# Plot created with method not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a module that creates a plot.  I want the plot to print if the user is in interactive mode.  The plot is created successfully and saved within the object and I can call it:

```
# this method creates the plot but no plot is displayed
myclass.create_plot()

# this successfully prints the plot
myclass.plot
```

But I want the function that creates the plot to print it out automatically.  I've tried this:

```
myclass(object):
    create_plot(self):
        ...
        self.plot = fig
        plt.draw()
```

I've tried this:

```
myclass(object):
    create_plot(self):
        ...
        self.plot = fig
        fig
```

...and nothing seems to get it to print out in ipython notebook (**and yes I am using %matplotlib inline**)

I am importing the class from a module where no display is specified in case that matters.

Here is the method that creates the plot:

```
def plot_grid_report(
        self,figsize=(15,7), score_nm='Score',
        start=None, end=None, border_color='#e5e5e5'
    ):


    # Remove any matplotlib formatting that might interfere
    rcdefaults()
    rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'

    # Transpose the test scores
    num_params = len(self._fitted_estimator.best_params_)
    test_samples = grid_report[start:end].ix[:,1+num_params:].T

    # Draw the figure
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15,7))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Set figure colors and remove grid
    fig.patch.set_facecolor(border_color)
    ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
    ax.grid(False)


    bp = plt.plot(
        range(1,len(test_samples.values[0])+1),
        test_samples.values[0],
        'ro')
    plt.xlim(0,len(test_samples.columns.values)+1)

    # Create xtick labels
    plt.xticks(range(1,len(test_samples.columns.values)+1), 
           test_samples.columns, 
           rotation='vertical',
           ha='center')    


    # plt.draw()
    plt.close(fig)
    warnings.filterwarnings('default') 
    return fig
```

Comment: How about a `plt.show()`?

Comment: plt.show does work, but adding that also causes code to stop if it's executed via command line.

Comment: yes, `plt.show` is blocking unless you have interactive mode turned on (`plt.ion()`)